# Line breaks often missing from lyrics on iPod

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod-touch, music

I like an orderly and well-documented music library, and one of the first things I do when I get new songs is to find the lyrics and put them on iTunes for my personal use. However, for several songs, the lyrics show without line breaks on my iPod.

I can't quite figure out the pattern. On iTunes, the line breaks all seem to be carriage return characters, both on songs where the line breaks show and where they don't.

I'm still using iOS 6, but I believe I had this issue since the earliest versions of iOS (I've had an iPod Touch since the first generation).

Comment: Welcome to the magical world of \r\n. (This isn't making fun of your question. It's making fun of line endings and the history of computers.)

Comment: @AndrewLarsson, funnily enough, I was under the impression that iOS, being in the OS X descent, would use \n.

Comment: It depends on what the source of the lyrics are and what line endings they used.

Comment: They're pretty much all from the Internet, where line breaks are denoted as paragraphs/<br> tags and translated  by iTunes/Mac OS X.